# tinymce shows replacement character instead of £ pound sign

Tags: tinymce, wordpress

I am using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-tinymce-description/ I am trying to get a £ pound sign rather than the replacement character � (a black diamond with a white question mark)

Answer (score 0):

You may add the charmap button to your button config. Using this character insertion button you will see the Pound-Character after insertion.
I guess in your case the character is not entered as html entity: `&pound;`

Comment: No that does not work, I think its something to do with (conflicting) document encoding...